# PHP / jQuery: How to get next row in SQL?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to get this next/previous image thing to work. But i don't know how to get this right. I only get the id 88 and 87, not the ones before that.

www.wallpapers.puffys.net

In my index.php page i got this code to show the image and get the next/previous image.

```
    include 'db_connect.php';

    #Last
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM images WHERE validated=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $last = $row['id'];

    #Next
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM images WHERE validated=1 AND id>'".$last."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $next = $row['id'];

    #Previous
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM images WHERE validated=1 AND id<'".$last."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $previous = $row['id'];

?>

<!--Scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function showLoader() {
            $('.loader').fadeIn(200);
        }

        function hideLoader() {
            $('.loader').fadeOut(200);
        }

        $(".next").click(function() {
            showLoader();                   
            $("#wallpaper").load("get.php?id=<? echo $next; ?>", hideLoader);
            return false;
        });

        $(".previous").click(function() {
            showLoader();
            $("#wallpaper").load("get.php?id=<? echo $previous; ?>", hideLoader);
            return false;
        });

        showLoader();
        $("#wallpaper").load("get.php?id=<? echo $last; ?>", hideLoader);

    });

</script>
```

The get.php page:

```
include 'db_connect.php';

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

if ($id) {

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE id='".$id."' AND validated=1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if ($num_rows[0] == 1) {

        $sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id='".$id."' AND validated=1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()."".$sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        echo '
        <img src="'.$row['image'].'" width="1024" height="576" alt="wallpaper" border="0">
        ';

    }

    else {

    }

}

else {  

}

?>
```

I know i am doing this wrong, but i don't know how to get this working. So i would hope someone could help me out.

Comment: -1 for mixing jquery and SQL in one question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely this;

```
#Next
$sql = "SELECT id FROM images WHERE validated=1 AND id>'".$last.
       "' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```

You get all IDs greater than the last, and order from highest to lowest which will give you the *highest* id available. You'll want to change it around to;

```
#Next
$sql = "SELECT id FROM images WHERE validated=1 AND id>'".$last.
       "' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0,1";
```

which will sort in the correct order and give you the *lowest* ID that is higher than the last.

Comment: This wont work. Since the PHP code is only executed once, i think.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball Yes, if you never call back to PHP you won't know the number of the next/previous image in your script. You should probably use an ajax callback to ask the server for that information.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
$NEW_ID = 0;

$SQL_FUNCTION = "SELECT ID FROM TableName";
$SQL_DATA = MYSQL_QUERY($SQL_FUNCTION); 
WHILE($SQLDAT = MYSQL_FETCH_OBJECT($SQL_DATA)){
   $ID = "$SQLDAT->ID";
   if($NEW_ID < $ID){$NEW_ID = $ID;} 
}
//NOW INSERT WITH THIS ID...
```

But I'm not sure if it works when more people simultaneously do this!?
(I would ask this question but i'm closed)